# Set an image from camera roll to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I've implemented a PickerController to have a user select an image, but I want the image the user selects to be displayed on the UIImageView I have.

I use the following to go to the camera roll:

```
- (void) makeUIImagePickerControllerForCamera:(BOOL)camera {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

[picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil]];


[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];


[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];

}
```

Which brings up the camera roll in which a user can click on a photo. However, after the click, it returns to the main view, which is obvious... But how can I assign an action to the button, or image the user selects. Something like `UIOKButton`?

Something like:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController presentModalViewController:nil image:nil] == UIOKButton ) {

NSArray *images = [UIImagePickerController images];

for(UIImage* pickerImage in [UIImagePickerController images])

{

myUIImage.image setImage pickerImage;
//^in the view

}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this.

All responses are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is already available:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269119/uiimagepickerview-controller-image-path-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void) makeUIImagePickerControllerForCamera:(BOOL)camera {

     UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     picker.delegate = self;
     picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

     [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil]];

     [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // Dismiss the picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Get the image from the result
    UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    myUIImage.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I retrieve the 'info' though, or the original image.

Comment: `info` is the second parameter to the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method from the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol. The image is called "image" in the sample code. Maybe I don't understand your follow up question.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but I'm talking about when I'm calling the method, how do I retrieve the original image, or 'info,' the second paramater of the method you provided. Thanks

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` supplies it to you when it calls that method on it's delegate.

Comment: You don't call that method manually. It's called for you by the `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method: [– imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a).